# Displaying errors with node.js

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, underscore.js

I want to be able to send a friendly error message to my user whenever I cannot connect to my MongoDB server from inside node.js, instead of just having `node.js` freaking out as it does  right now.

Apparently this won't work as I cannot access the response variable from outside a route method (`app.get('/' ...`), so what should I do instead?
No need to display something fancy, but just informing the user about a temporary problem would be amazing.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', function(err) {
    if (err) {
        //response.send('Temporary problem', 500); 
    }
});

// Routes
app.get('/', index.index);
//... And so on
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use alternative routes if connection error occured, so it won't be neccessary to perfom connection checks in every request handler.

```js
function connect() {
  mongoose.connect(connStr, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      // all GET requests will end with error message
      app.get('*', function(req, res) {
        res.end('DB error');
      });

      // handle errors, retry connection attempt or something...

      app.listen(...);
      return;
    }

    // Routes
    app.get('/', index.index);
    //... And so on

    app.listen(...);
  };
}

var app = express.createServer();
connect();
```

You should however find a way to drop route `'*'` when your connection will be up.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error displaying middleware in express. Put it after your router.

```
app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true }));
```

You can use it by calling `next()` within your route

```
app.get('/user/:userId', function(req, res, next){
  User.get(req.params.userId, function(err, user){
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.send('user ' + user.name);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a global variable from the block

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', function(err) {
    if (err) {
        //response.send('Temporary problem', 500); 
    }
});
```

If this global variable is true/false/..., the act accordingly in your route method.

Not the prettiest approach, but it'll work and is easy to implement.